# Segmentation Fault C language reading a simple word

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault, feof

I am writing using CodeBlocks, GCC and using C language. The code I have is as follows:

```
char word[50];
FILE *fn;
fn = open("word.txt", "rb");
if(fn == NULL) perror("File not opened");
while(!feof(fn))
{
    fscanf(fn, "%s", word);
}
```

The text file has only one word in it (at present that is "batman"). I have tried various versions of this code including the following:

```
char* word;
char = malloc(50);
FILE *fn;
fn = open("word.txt", "rb");
if(fn == NULL) perror("File not opened");
while(!feof(fn))
{
    fscanf(fn, "%s", &word);
}
```

I honestly don't know why (and why this should be SO difficult) but the error that CodeBlocks is giving me is the dreaded SIGSEV segmentation fault at the feof line. When I didn't do the while loop the fscanf would throw a Segmentation fault. Please help! I don't often work in C and I remember why now. Even the most simple of things can be SO difficult. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
I have actually got this to work (the top one) by changing the open line to:

```
fn = fopen("C://Temp//word.txt", "rb");
```

How can this work with relative paths?

Comment: `perror` just prints a message. It does not terminate the program. So if `fn` is null, bad things will happen.

Comment: If should be `fopen`, not `open` - and your compiler should be warning you about this - you are compiling with `gcc -Wall ...` I hope ?

Comment: Yes sorry it is giving a warning. @Mat I have made the program return and it is saying that word.txt is not a valid file or directory even though there is a word.txt in the same directory as the .exe file that I am running - am i missing something?

Comment: Don't ignore the compiler warnings - they are there for a good reason !

Comment: Your second code segment doesn't compile. Do you mean word = malloc(50) instead of char = malloc(50)?

Comment: Sorry guys, please see update.

Comment: Sorry sorted. It's just that CodeBlocks is being a pain in the proverbial - the file is fine if you click it from within Windows. For some reason codeblocks was ignoring it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
fn = open("word.txt", "rb");
```

to

```
fn = fopen("word.txt", "rb");
```

[`open`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open) returns an `int`, which is *not* a `FILE*`. [`feof`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/feof) and [`fscanf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) expect a `FILE*` not an int as its first parameter, that's the reason why `feof()` and, if you remove it, `fscanf()` segfaults.

And as others already noted, change `fscanf(fn, "%s", &word)` to `fscanf(fn, "%s", word)`.

Comment: Thanks Olaf. Please see the update at the bottom. Am still stuck on why this is not working.

Comment: Sorry Olaf. It's all working now, thanks for the pointers. (no pun intended)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that word is a char * (your code is not clear), this instruction will bring you problems:

```
fscanf(fn, "%s", &word);
```

Just change it by:

```
fscanf(fn, "%s", word);
```

Also, I suggest you to use the fopen function instead of open, since fscanf works with descriptors provided by fopen.

Comment: Thanks I think the fn value is null, however, the word.txt is in same folder as .exe what am I missing?

Comment: @DanielCasserly are you sure that `words.txt` is really a binary file ? if not then you should use `"r"` instead of `"rb"`.

Comment: Thanks i spotted that just now (well i looked it up)